# ASP.NET MVC - Create action link preserve query string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am currently writing my own paged list for ASP.NET Core MVC.

I struggle while creating the following:

I want to create a UrlHelper extension method:
Url.PageLink(int page, int pageSize)

Within that extension method I want to return a link which reuses ALL current values for controller, action, querystring and in addition it should add/update the page, pageSize values in the querystring as well.

Questions:
From where do I get the current controller and action in the UrlHelper object?
What is the best way to rebuild the querystring?
I can see it here url.ActionContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString... but do I really have to manually rebuild it? Or does something like AddQueryStringValue(int key, object value) exist?

Thanks so much in advance!!!
Simon

Comment: Where are you going to consume your URLHelper from? You need to devise a ViewModel that contains the information you need. Why are you using the Querystring?

Comment: I need the querystring because I want to make this method to work for any kind of view. I dont want to go with a specific viewmodel. I just want to create a extension method
public static string PageLink(this IUrlHelper url, int page, int pageSize)

Comment: I see. Well the QS itself is just a collection of key value pairs.. could you have that as a parameter in your ext. method?

Comment: Why should I pass it to the extension method when I can access it through url.ActionContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString ? My question is a different one... How can I preserve the current route- and querystring values while adding new querystring values.... and this only with help of current UrlHelper object...

Comment: Sorry..I didn't quite get the question...i've not used to UrlHelper much..

Comment: Hm not sure whats hard to understand here :-) I just want to render a link which takes into account ALL current request values (route values, query collection) and in addition I want to AddOrUpdate 2 values in the querystring. But the first part of the question is the important one....

Comment: Well it's sometimes difficult to understand the context. You have your site running in front of you, I have to make assumptions as to when and how you call you helper. Hopefuly someone will come up with an answer for you.

Comment: You re right... But the first part of my question in independent from my concrete application... it's a general asp.net core mvc question...

Answer (score 2):

Improvement of Simon's answer:
It can be called as `@Url.Current(new {page=42, id=5, foo=bar})`
It will preserve query string and update/add provided values.

```
public static class UrlHelperExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Get current URL with substituted values while preserving query string
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="helper"></param>
        /// <param name="substitutes">Query string parameters or route data paremers. E.g. new { action="Index", sort = "asc"}</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string Current(this IUrlHelper helper, object substitutes)
        {
            RouteValueDictionary routeData = new RouteValueDictionary(helper.ActionContext.RouteData.Values);
            IQueryCollection queryString = helper.ActionContext.HttpContext.Request.Query;

            //add query string parameters to the route data
            foreach (var param in queryString)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(queryString[param.Key]))
                {
                    //rd[param.Key] = qs[param.Value]; // does not assign the values!
                    routeData.Add(param.Key, param.Value);
                }
            }

            // override parameters we're changing in the route data
            //The unmatched parameters will be added as query string.
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor property in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(substitutes.GetType()))
            {
                var value = property.GetValue(substitutes);
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString()))
                {
                    routeData.Remove(property.Name);
                }
                else
                {
                    routeData[property.Name] = value;
                }
            }

            string url = helper.RouteUrl(routeData);
            return url;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The question asks for Asp.Net Core. I was trying to use shturm's answer on MVC 5 and could not get it to work. I took his same concepts and changed it to work with MVC 5. If anyone needs this verison, I'm posting it here. I also added the ability to change the action and controller.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Get URL with substituted values while preserving query string.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="helper">The url helper object we are extending.</param>
    /// <param name="action">The action we want to direct to.</param>
    /// <param name="controller">The controller we want to direct to.</param>
    /// <param name="substitutes">Query string parameters or route data paremers. E.g. new { action="Index", sort = "asc"}</param>
    /// <returns>The route string.</returns>
    public static String ActionWithOriginalQueryString(this UrlHelper helper, String action, String controller, object substitutes)
    {            
        RouteValueDictionary routeData = new RouteValueDictionary(helper.RequestContext.RouteData.Values);
        NameValueCollection queryString = helper.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString;

        //add query string parameters to the route data
        foreach (var param in queryString.AllKeys)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(queryString[param]))
            {
                //rd[param.Key] = qs[param.Value]; // does not assign the values!
                routeData.Add(param, queryString[param]);
            }
        }

        // override parameters we're changing in the route data
        //The unmatched parameters will be added as query string.
        foreach (PropertyDescriptor property in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(substitutes.GetType()))
        {
            var value = property.GetValue(substitutes);
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value?.ToString()))
            {
                routeData.Remove(property.Name);
            }
            else
            {
                routeData[property.Name] = value;
            }
        }

        //Set the controller and the action.
        routeData["controller"] = controller;
        routeData["action"] = action;

        //Return the route.
        return helper.RouteUrl(routeData);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have done it now like this:

```
public static class UrlHelperExtensions
{
    public static string Page(this IUrlHelper url, int page, int pageSize)
    {
        //Reuse existing route values
        RouteValueDictionary resultRouteValues = new RouteValueDictionary(url.ActionContext.RouteData.Values);

        //Add existing values from query string
        foreach (var queryValue in url.ActionContext.HttpContext.Request.Query)
        {
            if(resultRouteValues.ContainsKey(queryValue.Key))
                continue;

            resultRouteValues.Add(queryValue.Key, queryValue.Value);
        }

        //Set or add values for PagedList input model
        resultRouteValues[nameof(PagedListInputModel.Page)] = page;
        resultRouteValues[nameof(PagedListInputModel.PageSize)] = pageSize;

        return url.RouteUrl(resultRouteValues);
    }
}
```

And created a separate input model "PagedListInputModel" for just the pagedlist values... This way I can ensure that I can reuse it in all places and don't have to make sure that page and pageSize properties are included in all needed viewmodels with the correct name.

Any feedback is welcome.